# What is estimate of $\sum_{n\leq x\\gcd(n,r)=1} 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given any positive integer $r$, How to calculate the following estimate?
$$\sum_{n\leq x\\gcd(n,r)=1} 1$$

Comment: See "Euler function" from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#:~:text=Euler's%20totient%20function%20is%20a,defining%20the%20RSA%20encryption%20system. The formula you are looking for is between Euler Mascheroni constant and Menon's identity.

Comment: This counts the numbers n which are coprime to $r$ up to some maximum $x$.
By definition the numbers which are coprime to $r$ up to $r$ are
Euler's $\phi(r)$. In the range $r<x<2*r$ there are as many coprime numbers
as in the range $1\le x \le r$, because adding another $r$ to $x$ does not
change co-primality w.r.t. $r$. Because each interval of length $r$ adds
another $\phi(r)$, it's sufficient to count a full $\phi(r)$ for each
full interval (that's the floor function), and to count the irregular
numbers in the incomplete interval explicitly, that's $f(x mod n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $x$ is a positive integer, writing $x=ar+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers with $0\leq b<r$, you have
$$f(x):=\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\gcd(n,r)=1}} 1=\Big|\{n\in\Bbb{N}:\ n\leq x\ \wedge \gcd(n,r)=1\}\Big|=a\varphi(r)+f(b),$$
where $\varphi$ denotes Euler's totient function.